# How to return an interface type without mentioning the derived class name?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, types

I'm looking for a way to *not* reference the class name, yet still achieve the desired effect.
I can't do ITypedList.GetType() because it is an Interface.

```
public class DerivedList : ITypedList  
...  
public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetItemProperties()  
{  
    return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(DerivedList));  
}  
...
```

I'm wondering if this is possible.

Cheers,
edit: Trying to replace this with something that doesn't mention it's own class name

Comment: I find the question a little unclear, but it may just be me. Are you trying to replace this line 'return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(DerivedList));' with something that doesn't mention it's own class name?

Comment: Yes. Sorry if it was unclear, I'm quite the newbie here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely ...

```
    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetItemProperties()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this);  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `GetType` on the current instance:

```
return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.GetType());
```